# How can i check if two numbers start with the same digits Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check if two numbers start with the same digits, like startsWith but for numbers,

like,

```
let a = 567

let b = 5

a.startsWith(b) should return true, but it is returning not a function.
```

Comment: 1. Convert both of them to strings 2. use `.startsWith()`.

Comment: This is an essential lesson in software development and problem solving in general: You have problem A without immediate solution but you already recognize the similarity to a problem B with known solution X. If you cannot find a better direct solution for problem A, the next step should be "how can I turn situation A into situation B?" because after that you can apply solution X. In this case you should come up with the question "how do I turn a number into a string" (which is easily solveable through googling), and then everything will solve itself.

Comment: You can also do this using math: `let m = Math.floor(a / b);` to get the magnitude difference (100), then `Math.floor(a / m) == b`

Comment: @ChrisG yes you *can* do it with maths but your approach is wrong - returns `true` for `a = 567; b = 2;`: demo: https://jsbin.com/capamav/1/edit?js,console The maths route [is different](https://jsbin.com/kojexoj/1/edit). It's just easier to do it as a string, as you don't have to go figure it out.

Comment: @VLAZ Right! I missed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Convert `a` to a `String` as [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method is available on `Strings`.

**NOTE:** You can explicitly choose to convert `b` to a `String` but JavaScript will do it implicitly.

```js
const 
  a = 567,
  b = 5;

console.log(String(a).startsWith(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string.

`a.toString().startsWith(6)`

Your current variable is a number and it doesn't have startsWith method. startsWith method works on string. so you would need that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the numbers to strings first:

```js
let a = 567;
let b = 5;

console.log(a.toString().startsWith(b.toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative solutions to `String` and `toString()`, just to be thorough:

```js
let
  a = 567,
  b = 5;

console.log(`${a}`.startsWith(b));

console.log(('' + a).startsWith(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, you *can* use mathematics to do the comparison. But it is a bit involved.

1. To compare two arbitrary integers, you need to get them to a common magnitude - which power of 10 a number is in.
2. To get that, you need to do extract the base 10 logarithm of the number and only take the integer part: log<sub>10</sub> 567 is `2.75` of which you just need `2`. While log<sub>10</sub> 5 is `0.70` of which you need `0`.
3. When you have the exponents of each, then you can get the size to reduce the first number with the second exponent subtracted from the first exponent: `2 - 0 = 0`
4. Drop digits off the end of the number by doing an integer division by 10 to the power of the common exponent found in 3. so `Math.floor(567 / 10 ** 2)` which gives us `5`.

   - The divisor needs to further be capped to  be not lower than `0`. Otherwise a negative power of 10 will *increase* the number: `567 / 10 ** -2` is `56700` and we do not want to do that.
5. After the two numbers are brought to the same magnitude, compare them.

```js
function startsWithInteger(a, b) {
  //get which power of 10 each number is in
  const exponentA = Math.floor(Math.log10(a));
  const exponentB = Math.floor(Math.log10(b));
  
  //get magnitude to compare the two. Cap at 1 (10 ** 0)
  let comparativeMagnitude = 10 ** Math.max((exponentA - exponentB), 0);

  //get the "start of" of `a` with an intiger division
  //by the common power of 10 to get the same number of digits 
  const startA = Math.floor(a / comparativeMagnitude);
  
  return startA === b;
}

console.log(startsWithInteger(567, 2));    //false
console.log(startsWithInteger(267, 2));    //true
console.log(startsWithInteger(567, 50));   //false
console.log(startsWithInteger(567, 56));   //true
console.log(startsWithInteger(567, 5670)); //false
console.log(startsWithInteger(567, 567));  //true
```

With all that said, comparing as strings is a lot more convenient as you do not have to do all these operations or handle different cases that arise from this. For example, this is guaranteed to work for integers only, passing in numbers with a decimal part can give the wrong result.